# Is there a way to Delete inserted data, or vice versa?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I'm trying to get Data inserted and then Deleted in the same query.

I'm trying to delete it in chunks to not cause LOG issues:

```
DECLARE @BatchSize INT
SET @BatchSize = 100000

WHILE @BatchSize <> 0
BEGIN 
   
DELETE (@BatchSize) TABLE1 
WHERE   LogType = 'LOGTYPE'
AND     TABLE1.Id NOT IN (SELECT Id FROM TABLE2)
AND     TABLE1.Id IN     (SELECT Id FROM DifferentDB..TABLE3)
    
   SET @BatchSize = @@rowcount 
END
```

But this same query , I would like to insert data in a secondary DB first, and then delete.

Is it possible to achieve with no triggers? (inserted, deleted...)

I'm also open for a better delete in chunks approach, I just got that one by memory.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is pretty easy to do. I've written about it before here: [Simplifying Archival Processes](https://www.erikdarlingdata.com/sql-server/simplifying-archival-processes/)

A sample query would look sort of like this:

```
INSERT 
    dbo.Votes_Archive
(
    Id, 
    PostId, 
    UserId, 
    BountyAmount, 
    VoteTypeId, 
    CreationDate
)
SELECT 
    v.*
FROM 
(
    DELETE v
        OUTPUT
            Deleted.Id,
            Deleted.PostId,
            Deleted.UserId,
            Deleted.BountyAmount,
            Deleted.VoteTypeId,
            Deleted.CreationDate
    FROM dbo.Votes AS v
    WHERE v.UserId = 190597
) AS v;
```

You do need to be careful with OUTPUT, because if your [target is a client application or table variable](https://www.erikdarlingdata.com/sql-server/mind-your-output-targets/), the plan will be forced serial.

Comment: Also in either of those two cases a rolled back `delete` will still return data (which is actually useful in debugging scenarios)